# ImportError: cannot import name 'LLaMATokenizer' from 'transformers'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, alpaca, llama-index

I am not able to import **LLaMATokenizer**

Any solution for this problem?

I am using the code of this repo.
https://github.com/zphang/transformers/tree/llama_push
and trying to load the models and tokenizer using

```
tokenizer = transformers.LLaMATokenizer.from_pretrained("./weights/tokenizer/")
model = transformers.LLaMAForCausalLM.from_pretrained("./weights/llama-7b/")
```

which results in the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'LLaMATokenizer' from 'transformers'

Answer (score 12):

To complement [cronoik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664872/cronoik) answer (that is the correct answer):

If you still having problems with `from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer` try to install the package directly from github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

also don't forget to change the Tokenizer config file from *LLaMATokenizer* to *LlamaTokenizer*.

source: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/22222

Answer (score 2):

The second `L` and `MA` are lowercased in the class names: [LlamaTokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/llama#transformers.LlamaTokenizer) and [LlamaForCausalLM](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/llama#transformers.LlamaForCausalLM)

```py
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer

model_id = "my_weights/"

tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id,
```

---

One quick way is to figure the right case for the variables is going to the commits and doing a ctr+F on the browser, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/compare/main...zphang:transformers:llama_push

Comment: Interesting feature suggestion: Why don't the import error message suggest fixes for objects that spells similar/the same but of different case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75909708/610569 =)

Comment: Thanks I resolved the issue with my local environment. But when i try to pass the git command in sagemaker training job to execute Specific PR that allows me to use weights. i get errors. 

is there any different way to install packages in sagemaker training job?

Comment: @ScrapperMaster please create a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct imports will make this go away. Use the below code to run:
Use the reference here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/llama

```
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer
model_id = "/root/models/models_hf/7B/"
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)

prompt = "I am looking for a good phone"
inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
generate_ids = model.generate(inputs.input_ids, max_length=50)
tokenizer.batch_decode(generate_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False)[0]

## Output
## 'I am looking for a good phone that is not too expensive. I am not looking for a smart phone. I am looking for a phone that is easy to use and has a good camera. I am looking for a phone that is not too'
```